# How to loop if the page automatically refresh after loop 1 and don't want to continue loop 2 in Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Please suggest me how to loop for tr[1], [2], [3] or N numbers, following the table provided on the website automatically if the page automatically refresh after loop 1 and don't want to continue loop 2, loop 3, loop N?

> so like this for example: loop 1 (page auto refresh) > loop 2 (page auto refresh) > loop N (page auto refresh) | **This auto refresh page is directly from the website, not from the code*

code:

```
try:
    while True:
        browser.get('URL')
        options = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="event"]/tbody/tr')
        for opt in options:
            opt.find_element_by_xpath('./td[9]').click()
            time.sleep(2.5)
            break
except (ElementNotVisibleException, WebDriverException, NoSuchElementException):
        pass
```

here is a **loop while** for iterating continuously when the for loop has reached the loop N on the website
I suggest there is an error in the **loop for**, but I don't know where it is so that I can continue the loop

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the page refreshes after the `click` operation on the `td` tags, for the next iteration the element `options` is no longer found(Since the page got refreshed).

Try to find the element `options` on each iteration so that the element is found even after page refresh.

```
try:
    while True:
        browser.get('URL')
        options = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="event"]/tbody/tr')
        for i in range(len(options)):
            options = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="event"]/tbody/tr')
            options[i].find_element_by_xpath('./td[9]').click()
            time.sleep(2.5)
            break
except (ElementNotVisibleException, WebDriverException, NoSuchElementException):
        pass
```